# Why am I getting a TypeError choices.map is not a function?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, axios, material-ui, menuitem

I am trying to map the items (choices) in an array to a `<select>` field with `<MenuItem>`, I am very close but I am getting a `TypeError choices.map is not a function` error.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    minWidth: 250,
  },
  selectEmpty: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
  },
}));
```

Below is the section in which the issue is, above is just styling.

```
function SimpleSelect() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
    firm: '',
    infosys: '',
    spot: '',
  });
  const [choices, setChoices] = React.useState([])

    const inputLabel = React.useRef(null);
  const [labelWidth, setLabelWidth] = React.useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios(
        'http://127.0.0.1:5000/form/'
      );

      setChoices({ choices: result.data })
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  function handleChange(event) {
    setValues(values)
  }

return (
    <form className={classes.root} autoComplete="off">
      <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel htmlFor="firm-helper">Firm</InputLabel>
        <Select
          value={values.firm}
          onChange={handleChange}
          input={<Input name="firm" id="firm-helper" />}
        >
          {choices.map((choice, index) =>
          <MenuItem key={index} value={index} primaryText={choice} /> 
          )}
        </Select>
        </Select>
        <FormHelperText>Select a Firm</FormHelperText>
      </FormControl>
    </form>
  );
}

export default SimpleSelect;
```

**I am currently getting this:**

```
sed-vars
  Line 39:  Effect callbacks are synchronous to prevent race conditions. Put the async function inside:

useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchData() {
    // You can await here
    const response = await MyAPI.getData(someId);
    // ...
  }
  fetchData();
}, [someId]); // Or [] if effect doesn't need props or state
```

I do receive a JSON response of an array with the axios request. I'll also eventually need each form `handelChange(event)` to create a POST request to my endpoint.

Comment: Can you confirm that `result.data` is an alterable array?

Comment: How can I check for this? I am new to React JS and Javascript

Comment: Since you're using `async/await` you can just write  `console.log(result.data)` right before you do `setChoices(result.data)`. Please share what you find.

Answer (score 2):

***Edit:*** I made an example using a public API - you need to have your component look something like this..

***Live Demo/Example:***

[image: Edit condescending-shadow-gmn6c]

***SimpleSelect***

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import {
  FormControl,
  Select,
  FormHelperText,
  Input,
  InputLabel,
  MenuItem
} from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    flexWrap: "wrap"
  },
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    minWidth: 250
  },
  selectEmpty: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2)
  }
}));

function SimpleSelect() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [choices, setChoices] = useState([]);
  const [selectedChoice, setSelectedChoice] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios(
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?_limit=10"
      );
      setChoices(result.data);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  function handleChange(event) {
    setSelectedChoice(event.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form className={classes.root} autoComplete="off">
        <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
          <InputLabel htmlFor="firm-helper">Firm</InputLabel>
          {/*
            PLESE CONSOLE.LOG SO YOU CAN SEE WHAT IS IN YOUR API RESPONSE!!!
          */}
          {console.log(choices)}
          <Select
            value={selectedChoice}
            onChange={handleChange}
            input={<Input name="firm" id="firm-helper" />}
          >
            {choices.map((choice, index) => (
              <MenuItem key={index} value={choice}>
                {choice.title}
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
          </Select>
          <FormHelperText>Select a Firm</FormHelperText>
        </FormControl>
      </form>
      {selectedChoice ? (
        <div>
          <h4>Selected Choice:</h4>
          <pre>{JSON.stringify(selectedChoice, null, 2)}</pre>
        </div>
      ) : (
        ""
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default SimpleSelect;
```

---

***Original Answer:***

It looks like the issue has to do with how you are originally setting your `choices` state.. When your component is mounted, and you are waiting for data to arrive, you are using `map` like: `choices.map(...)` - which, would need to be: `choices.choices.map(...)`, due to how you have your initial state set..

Changing to `choices.choices.map(...)` would get your component loaded, but you would again encounter that same error after your data has arrived, this is due to how you are setting `choices` inside of `useEffect`...see below for more info, but you would need to change `useEffect` to: `setChoices({ choices: data.results })`

---

*If you **do not** want to use `choices.choices` - all you have to do is change:*

- **This:**

```
      const [choices, setChoices] = React.useState({
        choices: [],
      })
```

- **To This:**

```
      const [choices, setChoices] = React.useState([])
```

---

*If you want to keep using `choices.choices`, you will need to change:*

- **The `map` from:**

```
  {choices.map((choice, index) =>
    <MenuItem key={index} value={index} primaryText={choice} /> 
  )}
```

- **To:**

```
  {choices.choices.map((choice, index) =>
    <MenuItem key={index} value={index} primaryText={choice} /> 
  )}
```

**~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
AND
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~**

- **The `useEffect` from:**

```
React.useEffect(() => {
 // other code here
  setChoices(result.data);
})
```

- **To:**

```
React.useEffect(() => {
 // other code here
  setChoices({ choices: result.data });
})
```

---

Also, as others have mentioned, you'll need to verify the contents of `results.data` are iterable, and can be `map`ped over..

Comment: Thank you for this. I made the changes in order to be able to use just choices. map. I also changed my ```useEffect()``` to what you said but still get choices.map is not a function.

Comment: It sounds like your issue may be with the data you are receiving.. if you comment out your `{choices.map(...)}` code and put the following code in its place: '`{console.log(choices)}`' - what does your console show? Can you update your question with the results that get output to your console, please?

Comment: I am not logging asnything. It seems like my axios request is broken now, I am unable to get anything from it. I do not see my array displayed in the select dropdown like I did before.

Comment: Ah yeah I should have seen that - I think having multiple useEffects is an issue, when they both have the same dependency array.. Can you try removing the first useEffect, where you setLabelWidth, and change this `const [labelWidth, setLabelWidth] = React.useState(0);` to this `const [labelWidth, setLabelWidth] = React.useState(75);` - Also, as the error suggest, put the `async` function inside of useEffect...

Comment: I did this but I still do not have any data from my axios request. This was working before I posted the question, not sure where something changed....

Comment: I also updated my code to show what I currently have

Comment: @goto1 yes I am

Comment: After all the changes that have been suggested above? Is the code in your answer your current code? And what does `console.log(result)` look like after you do that `axios` call?

Comment: @Alex - like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-shadow-gmn6c?fontsize=14

Comment: @MattOestreich I've updated my question. Now my logs are different. There are no breaking errors but I am still not getting anything from axios. when I try to console.log right before setState

Comment: Your code is still wrong from the first issue - you need to fix your useEffect - you did not update your code accordingly. Please see my original answer.

Comment: nvm, I am getting data from axios. But still am not getting an accurate mapping from the array. The select drop down has become very long, but each entry is empty.

Comment: @MattOestreich If I use ```<MenutItem>{choices}</MenutItem>``` I get the fetched array.

However, if I try to map I get an empty value for each item in the array.

Comment: Please post the results you get - is it even an array?

Comment: ```{choices}``` seems to be a single string with each of my array items. No spaces, commas, etc @MattOestreich

Comment: However, the JSON data in the request is an array.

Comment: That is because it is JSON data in string form.. I have updated my answer with some example code, as well as a live demo using a public API.....With all due respect, and no offense, if you are having issues simply console logging your API response - you may want to bite off a little less than you are currently trying to chew.  Take a step back and understand how APIs work, how to log an API response, learn the fundamentals of React before mixing complex tasks, etc...